# What about $get.Constructor{} in AngularJS 1.3 directive link function?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I made an AngularJS directive which works in AngularJS 1.2 but after updating my application to AngularJS 1.3 the fourth parameter of my link function does not contain an array of controller instances anymore but an array of *$get.Constructor {}* items.

```
jtApp.directive("jtWizard", ["$q", "$timeout", function ($q, $timeout) {
    return {
        require: ["^ngController", "jtWizard"],
        restrict: "E",
        replace: false,
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: "App/Components/wizard.htm",
        scope: {
            mainHeader: "@"
        },
        controller: "jtWizardController",
        link: function postLink(scope, elm, attrs, controllers, transcludeFn) {
            ...
            var userWizardController = controllers[0];
            var jtWizardController = controllers[1];
            ...
        }
);
```

Any ideas about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.3 changes how directive controllers are created, controllers are now instances of `Constructor`, I believe it is a side effect of commit [5f3f25a1](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/5f3f25a1a6f9d4f2a66e2700df3b9c5606f1c255). This also means you cannot return an object to define a controller, rather must modify the controllers members directly.

```
controller: function() { this.foo = "bar"; }
```

rather than

```
controller: function() { return { foo: "bar" }; }
```

Functionality should otherwise remain backwards compatible.